# updater content to ++ 1 in the database - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

it is such that I must have built such that when kommmer into articles that sends up the database +1 each time you load the page,

I have done like this:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);

    string viewSet = "1";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;


    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Artikler SET viewSet = @viewSet++1 WHERE Id = @id;";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@viewSet", viewSet);


    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

**comes nothing into the database**

Comment: If nothing is updated then you have no records in the table with `id = @id`.

Comment: It will still not works mænd can be because ved that has spent SqlDataSource on page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Artikler SET viewset = ISNULL(viewset + 1, 1) WHERE Id = @id
```

Set the initial viewset if its null to 1, otherwise increase it.  You don't need to pass the parameter. (unless you are trying to set the initial value to something other than 1?)

Answer (score 0):

It's an update so you need to have at least one row with given Id. Then run this update on your DB:

```
UPDATE Artikler SET viewSet = 0 WHERE Id = @id --it will clear counter
```

Then you can modify your CommandText:

```
UPDATE Artikler SET viewSet += 1 WHERE Id = @id; --it will increment by 1 previous number
```

Using that CommandText you don't need to know previous state of viewSet so you don't need to pass it as param.